# Transparent wall or Force field in the middle where planes, cars, birds hit

Tags: identify-this-movie

Please help to identify this movie. In the scene the main lead is driving a car,suddenly loses control and ends in a field, his tire is punctured. Suddenly he notices a thin transparent wall just hit the floor in the entire length of his vision, he sees a cow been cut in half because of the wall. Then he sees birds falling down with their neck snapped. Then notices a plane flying over his head and it crashes into the transparent wall. He sees fire trucks coming from the other side of the wall but cant hear their sirens, he stands in the middle of the road signalling them to stop and the trucks stop in fear of running him over.
This is all I saw in a trailer online and could not identify the movie

Comment: Please try adding some more details like, approx year of release, motion picture/animation, genre of the film etc. Could be Midnight Special http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2649554/ or Maze Runner different versions. Possible year of release is helpful in these cases.

Comment: You're thinking of the show Under the Dome, a Stephen King adaptation. Here is a link to the cow being cut in half scene - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7vNfN0f1d4

Answer (score 35):

I haven't seen it or know much about it, but it perhaps could be Stephen King's [Under the Dome (2013)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_the_Dome_(TV_series)) tv series.  [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_Y5YeYrqUk&feature=youtu.be)

> Under the Dome tells the story of the residents of the fictional small
>   town of Chester's Mill, when a massive, transparent, indestructible
>   dome suddenly cuts them off from the rest of the world. Military
>   forces, the government, and the media positioned outside the barrier
>   attempt to break it down, while the residents trapped inside must find
>   their own ways to survive with diminishing resources and rising
>   tensions. A small group of people inside the dome must also unravel
>   complicated mysteries to figure out what the dome is, where it came
>   from, and when (and if) it will go away

Comment: Definitely reminds me of the novel.

Comment: Was about to say the same (based only on reading the book). The trailer more or less matches the OP's description beat-for-beat https://youtu.be/f_Y5YeYrqUk

Comment: (The bifurcated cow is in the background at 1:05)

Comment: @Tilbs neat, I added the trailer link into my post.  thank you

Comment: For the cow scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7vNfN0f1d4

Comment: Definitely under the dome - the pilot. I remember the cow. Looks like someone posted the trailer.

Comment: Funny about the parallels with The Simpsons Movie!

Comment: I guess the simpson movie was inspired by the novel @Muzer

Comment: @Marv the novel came out in 2009, Simpsons Movie was 2007. Stephen King claims it was a coincidence which I'm inclined to believe since he doesn't seem the type to watch Simpsons post-decline.

Comment: Oh I guess I mixed up the dates, thought it was the other way around. It really is an amazing coincidence

Comment: @Muzer: it’s also believable as neither did actually invent the concept of such domes.